# How to provide facility to download & upload files to specific type of user in drupal 6

Tags: views, 7, files

**What i did:-**

So , i am create one content type like "login_page", so in that i want to display title , description and file download & display. This content type display on when user logged in instead of user page . And i have 2 types of user i.e Customer user & guest user.

**What i want:-**
So now i want to display or download text file such as pdf or doc files facility to **customer user** & display facility to **guest user** . This files are uploaded by the admin.

So for that any module is available or any solution nearly same to such situation. Please help me i am stuck on that.

Answer (score 1):

Create two roles namely "customer" and "guest" (if you had not created yet). Now you can use [field_permissions](http://drupal.org/project/field_permissions) to give each role the  permission you want. Add permission to customer role to download it and guest to view it.